# Using tikzpicture in beamer to make a directed acrylic graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I am trying to add a directed acrylic graph to a beamer presentation. Using [this code](http://codealamode.blogspot.com/2013/06/drawing-dags-latex-solution.html) (reproduced below) I created a slide, but the image produced has every node and arrow stacked roughly on top of one another. I've tried playing with the positions of the nodes, but no matter what positions I enter they seem to stack on top of one another in the image.
How do I get it to display correctly (like the image below from the site) in beamer?

[image: DAG of IV]

```
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% nodes %
\node[text centered] (z) {$Z$};
\node[right = 1.5 of z, text centered] (t) {$T$};
\node[right=1.5 of t, text centered] (y) {$Y$};
\node[draw, rectangle, dashed, above = 1 of t, text centered] (u) {$U$};

% edges %
\draw[->, line width= 1] (z) --  (t);
\draw [->, line width= 1] (t) -- (y);
\draw[->,red, line width= 1,dashed] (u) --node {X} (z);
\draw[->,line width= 1] (u) --(t);
\draw[->,line width= 1] (u) -- (y);
\draw[->, red, line width=1,dashed] (z) to  [out=270,in=270, looseness=0.5] node{X} (y);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}
```

Comment: Did you write `\usetikzlibrary{positioning}` in your preamble? Please post a complete code that can be compiled by anyone (see [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) ).

Comment: Thanks! That did it. The website I got from the example said to use `\usepackage{pgf,tikz}` with no mention of positioning.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it has been resolved in the comments

Comment: "This question appears to be off-topic because it has been resolved in the comments." How nonsensical. The question is specifically about using a package in LaTeX. It's as if you're saying that questions about LaTeX as having no easy solution by definition. The question got answered in the comments ?! No way that's about LaTeX!